# How to collect states of buggy components using ErrorBoundary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem briefly: I want somehow gather states of buggy components using ErrorBoundary.

I use typical ErrorBoundary component in the project.
Something like this:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    let errorLogger = new ErrorLoger();

    errorLogger.sendError(error.message, errorInfo, this.props.children.props);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (<p>Something went wrong. Please try again later</p>);
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }

  export default ErrorBoundary;
```

ErrorLoger is a class I use to send errors to external service.

I wrap my functional and class components around the project like this:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <Footer/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

When an error is caught, I get info about the buggy component and I can find the exact line, that broke the render.

But for come errors that I can't reproduce locally it would be crucial to log state or even some key properties, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Comment: the error stack is what usually gets propagated to the `componentDidCatch` / `getDerivedStateFromError` lifecycle hook. If you want to catch the state, you would need to set up the error boundary within the same component itself. As react components are dynamic it won't be possible to access the state from external components until and unless they are set in a context.

Comment: @sumit-surana Oh, thank you for the answer! I want to clarify: that means, that I have to add `componentDidCatch` and `getDerivedStateFromError` to every component to achieve my goal? And send to logger `this.state` in `componentDidCatch`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. If you want to send the state information, that is the only way, if you don't know from where your errors might originate.

Comment: or another option is to know where might your error come up, and write a custom error which sends back the state object when thrown as a JSON string, which you can parse and send back to the server.

Comment: @sumit-surana Thanks a lot!